Generic function type validation
Is there a way, particularly as part of the function definition, for us to enforce a type constraint on the function definition?
For instance:
type IMyFunc<P = any,R = any> = (p: P) => R;

function myFunc<P = any, R = any>(p: P):R { ... }

How can we have the Typescript compiler validate that myFunc is an implementation of the interface IMyFunc?
One way I've found would be to use a separate declaration to validate this...
const f: IMyFunc = myFunc;

However, in this case the generic type parameters default to any (So you can't export and use f except in the default case). I suppose it is better than nothing, but I'd prefer something more succinct if it exists - preferably something that I can supply as part of the definition of myFunc.
For instance, it would be nice if you could do this:
function myFunc<P = any, R = any>(params: P):R {
  ...
} : IMyFunc<P,R>;


This is multiple issues. 1: your IMyFunc type doesn't accurately capture what a generic function does; you have your type params in the wrong scope. The correct scope looks like this. 2: no, you cannot annotate functions. There's a feature request at ms/TS#22063 but it hasn't been implemented; you're stuck with a separate line of validation code. Does this fully address the question? If so, please [edit] to make it clear which of the 2 issues you're asking about & I'll write an answer. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Not sure what you mean by IMyFunc not accurately capturing what a generic function does? It is valid syntax however, try it out. But +1 on the feature request! I think that essentially answers my question; this is just a blind spot in Typescript at the moment, but hopefully something that will be improved in the future.

It's valid syntax but it's not what you mean. type X<T> = (x: T) => T is not the same as type X = <T>(x: T) => T. You want the latter, not the former. Do you see the difference? Since you are asking about the annotation and not the generic scoping, perhaps you'd [edit] the question to move the type parameters to the right place and we can just answer with something about ms/TS#22063 and forget about the whole generic part of the question?

@jcalz actually I want the one I specified. I'm not looking to describe a function that can take any generic input and provide any generic output (which wouldn't be a terribly useful type check). In practice, I want to provide a generic definition (like type IPluginHook<P, D> = (params: P): IPlugin ) and then provide specific implementations thereof with more restricted type parameters

Then why is your example usingmyFunc, and why are you concerned that f is no longer generic? You either want a generic function or a generic type; which is it? Please [edit] the question to clarify. Or, better yet, remove the whole generic weirdness and just ask “can I annotate a function statement without an external line of code” and we can answer with “no, there’s a feature request.” Right now your question is still asking about two distinct issues that are only related in that they both occur in your code.

I want a generic function that I can apply further restrictions to. Basically the same type checking functionality as with interfaces and classes; you can start with a base definition that is highly generic and then through subsequent derivations those type parameters become more specific.

But you haven’t written that type. Your type is a generic type that refers to a nongeneric function, while your function itself is generic. There’s a mismatch and the only reason it compiles at all is because of defaults and any. It’s quite possible there’s a way to write what you want, but you’re not demonstrating it here. Given that you already accepted the answer to the question, can we agree that the annotation is the primary issue here and the generic scoping is not? If so, please, [edit] the question to remove the confusing mismatch, for the sake of future readers.

@jcaltz If I knew how to express what I want in Typscript I wouldn't have asked a question. Your supplied answer gets to the heart of the matter: Typescript doesn't provide the tools to describe what I want to do. But I don't agree that how you scope the generics is irrelevant to the problem. The way that I've expressed it above is much closer to the desired goal than is the one you've suggested; Describing a purely generic function is not the goal - the goal is to be able to validate generic function signatures, including refining those signatures with more specific type parameters.

I guess we’ve reached an impasse, since at this point I would just repeat things I’ve already said. I’ll disengage now.

There is currently no way to annotate a function statement so that its call signature conforms to an existing function type. There's a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#22063 for that. If you want to see it happen, it wouldn't hurt for you to give it a . It probably also wouldn't help very much, since even very highly upvoted feature requests don't always get implemented.
Until or unless something changes, then, you'll need to do such checking a different way. You could do what you did with const f: IMyFunc = myFunc;, or even just define const myFunc: IMyFunc = function (p) { ⋯ }.

Your scoping is incorrect, but the rest of your answer properly addresses the question. Thanks! Guess I'll just have to wait and hope the Typescript team gets around to making this improvement at some point.

Let’s edit the question and answer to remove the generic weirdness since the scoping is apparently not the primary issue.

There is one way to do this. But you should know that the definition of the function will be the same and you cannot make it shorter, because you need to get those generic types anyway.
To specify a type for a variable that points to a generic function, you should define an interface like this:
interface MyGenericFn {
  //You don't need to set `any` as a default value because it's already the default value
  <P,R>(p: P): R;
}

function myFunc<P, R>(p: P): R { ... }

const f: MyGenericFn = myFunc;

You can read more in detail from the official documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types)

Hmm, this approach appears to have its own limitations. Namely: it doesn't appear like you can restrict the type parameters in the interface. To properly implement this interface, your function would need to work for the full range of types that could be passed in for P and R. In my case, I'd very much like to have a general, generic definition followed up by specific implementations with specific types (so caller would not send in the generic type params). So for the ability to restrict types I'll have to stick to the type declaration approach. This seems like a blind-spot in Typescript.

TypeScript uses structural equivalence instead of name equivalence for comparing values. That also applies to functions (being values of type Function).
That means, that your myFunc function does not need to explicitly comply to the IMyFunc type upon definition. The compiler will still check if you try to use your myFunc function in an illegal way.
type IMyFunc<P, R> = (p: P) => R;
/* or:
interface IMyFunc<P, R> {
  (p: P): R
}
*/

function doSomething<P, R>(func: IMyFunc<P, R>, params: P) {
  console.log("Running the doSomething function...")
  const value: R = func(params);
  console.log("The value returned by func is " + value);
}

function myFunc(p: number): string {
  return "Value of p is " + p;
}

doSomething<number, string>(myFunc, 42);
doSomething<string, string>(myFunc, "42");

The first call of doSomething will succeed, because the signature of myFunc complies with the IMyFunc<int, string> type of the func parameter of doSomething.
The second call of doSomething will fail, because there it expects to receive a func of type IMyFunc<string, string>.
EDIT
If you really want to let the TypeScript compiler check that your myFunc function definition complies to a signature defined by an IMyFunc type, you cannot use the traditional function definition syntax. In that case you should define your function by binding it to a variable.
Instead of
function myFunc(p: number): string {
  return "Value of p is " + p;
}

you could write
const myFunc: IMyFunc<int, string> = function (p) {
  return "Value of p is " + p;
}

I would normally argue against it, but for the sake of completeness:
If you want to mimic the declaration behavior of traditional function definitions more closely, you might want to try the var keyword instead of let or const keywords. That way, variable hoisting will be effective:
var myFunc: IMyFunc<int, string> = function (p) {
  return "Value of p is " + p;
}


I understand Structural Equivalence - and it is very powerful. Yet if you implement an interface and leave something out, the compiler will give you errors in the place that you declare the implementation - not in the location that you attempt to use it. You are correct that you'll get an error if you attempt to use a function and it doesn't meet the expected signature, but it'd be much nicer if the compiler could provide the same kind of type checking as when implementing an interface at the place of declaration. Not a complaint of your answer, just wanting more out of Typescript :P Thanks!

@RyanPierceWilliams  Ah. In that case, I think that jcalz is right. That is currently not supported in TypeScript. If you really want that, it seems that you currently can only use the explicit variable binding syntax. I will edit my answer to include an example.
